# Extraction IO data inside other Monad

Tags: ios, haskell, monads

I am using HDBC-Sqlite3, I would like to make queries depending on the page I am in. And I would like to get the data out of the IO Monad. It should be possible because "get" is already not pure. How is it done in Haskell in general?

```
  main = do
  conn <- connectSqlite3 "test.db"
  scotty 3000 $ do
    get "/" $ do
      x <- quickQuery' conn "SELECT * from definitions" [] -- Here, how to do it?
      blaze $ Mathskell.Views.Read.render conn
```

The problem is that I'm in a "do" where the Monad is ActionM and not IO.

I thought about constructing an ActionM from the IO, and then using the x <- ... syntax, is it a good solution?
I also saw the existence of liftIO/liftM but I didn't understand how/when to use it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that specific library, but typically one injects an IO action into another monad with `liftIO`. This is indeed what you hint at in your question.

I would try something like

```
get "/" $ do
  x <- liftIO $ quickQuery' conn "SELECT * from definitions" []
  blaze $ Mathskell.Views.Read.render conn
```

This should work as long as the outer monad has a `MonadIO` instance.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But oddly enough, it requires a ";" at the end of the "x <- ..." line otherwise he thinks that it's only one statement, and the last statement needs to be an expression. Any hint why? I think this is because the nomad created can take more arguments

Comment: @x4rkz semicolons only help if you have the wrong indentation. Check if every entry in the `do` block is indented at the same level. If I indented `blaze $ ...` more, for instance, that would be a part of the previous entry, which would trigger the error you mention.

Comment: I've done that already, removed the indentation and make sure I put the same.

Comment: I did it again, and it works, I should have done it wrong, thank you!